# Rails 5 - Simple Form - namespaced resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, simple-form

I am trying to learn how to use namespacing in my Rails 5 app.

I have a resource called randd_fields.

The table in the database is called:

```
randd_fields
```

I have model.rb files with:

randd.rb

```
module Randd
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'randd_'
  end
end

class Randd::Field < ApplicationRecord
end
```

The controller is called:

The views are organised in files with views/rannd/fields

In my _form.html.erb, I'm trying to find a way to get the form to render.

I have tried each of these.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@field), multipart: true do |f| %>
<%= simple_form_for(@randd, @field), multipart: true do |f| %>
<%= simple_form_for([:randd, @field]), multipart: true do |f| %>
```

Each of them gives an error:

The first, gives an error that says:
    undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass

The second 2 give an error that says:

```
syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
...r([:randd, @field]), multipart: true do |f| @output_buffer.s...
```

How can I use the new path to a namespaced resource?

My routes show:

```
rake routes | grep field
                  import_randd_fields POST     /randd/fields/import(.:format)                                          randd/fields#import
                         randd_fields GET      /randd/fields(.:format)                                                 randd/fields#index
                                      POST     /randd/fields(.:format)                                                 randd/fields#create
                      new_randd_field GET      /randd/fields/new(.:format)                                             randd/fields#new
                     edit_randd_field GET      /randd/fields/:id/edit(.:format)                                        randd/fields#edit
                          randd_field GET      /randd/fields/:id(.:format)                                             randd/fields#show
                                      PATCH    /randd/fields/:id(.:format)                                             randd/fields#update
                                      PUT      /randd/fields/:id(.:format)                                             randd/fields#update
                                      DELETE   /randd/fields/:id(.:format)                                             randd/fields#destroy
```

I can't find a way to get the form to render to create a new randd_field instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
<%= simple_form_for @field, multipart: true do |f| %>
```

Comment: That gives this error: undefined method `randd_randd_fields_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f8095407988>:0x007f809c2633a0>
Did you mean?  randd_fields_path

Comment: ok, I got it, this form is to create a new field, right? then could you please add your `fields_controller#create` code?

Comment: I edited the answer, could you try it and add the errors message and your `fields_controller#create` code?